# How can I access the state of "clicked" in this piece of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this piece of jQuery. Is it possible to determine whether the `#mydiv` element has been  "clicked" from outside this piece of code.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/byronyasgur/BxF9R/)

```
$.fn.clicktoggle = function(a, b) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var clicked = false;
        $(this).bind("click", function() {
            if (clicked) {
                clicked = false;
                return b.apply(this, arguments);
            }
            clicked = true;
            return a.apply(this, arguments);
        });
    });
};

function odd() {
    alert("odd");
}

function even() {
    alert("even");
}

$("#mydiv").clicktoggle(even, odd);
```

Comment: What does this mean - ""clicked" from outside this piece of code"

Comment: whether `clicked = ;` `true` or `false` ... can I somehow access that variable from somewhere else in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to determine whether the #mydiv element has been "clicked" from outside this piece of code.

No. As far as I can see from the code you've quoted, that information is only stored in a variable contained in the execution context of a function call (the `clicked` variable in the `each` iterator function). That information is completely private to that context.

It would be easy to modify the code so that that information were available. For instance:

```
$.fn.clicktoggle = function(a, b) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.bind("click", function() {
            if ($this.attr("data-clicked")) {
                $this.attr("data-clicked", "");
                return b.apply(this, arguments);
            }
            $this.attr("data-clicked", "Y");
            return a.apply(this, arguments);
        });
    });
};
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BxF9R/7/)

There, instead of storing the state in a `clicked` variable, we store it as a `data-clicked` attribute on the element (either `""` [a "falsey" value] if not clicked, or `"Y"` [a "truthy" value] if clicked). You could then know, from outside, what the state of that was by doing:

```
if ($("#mydiv").attr("data-clicked")) {
    // It has the "clicked" state
}
else {
    // It has the un-"clicked" state
}
```

But if the information is purely stored in the variable, as in the code you've shown, that information is completely hidden from "outside."